# What is the homology group $H_0(\Bbb Q)$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I was studying Hatcher's book and was curious about what the group $H_0(\mathbb{Q})$ would be.  Does anyone know what it is?  Help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: $H_0(\mathbb{Q})$ is the free abelian group on the connected components of $\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{Q}$ is totally disconnected.

Comment: So would it be the direct product of countably many copies of $\mathbb{Z}?$

Comment: @user68072 No. The direct sum--the difference matters here!

Comment: @user68072: But $H^0(\mathbb Q)$ would be the direct product of countably many copies of $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: What is $H^0(\mathbb{Q})?$

Comment: @user68072: the 0th *co*homology group.

Comment: **Path** connected components.